# Monitoring Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have timer triggered Function. It is executed every minute but I don't see any logs in Monitor section in Azure Portal.

[image: Monitor]

However when I click "Run query in Application Insights" and fix cloudRoleName in query (by default it is set to name of application but we changed it with `ITelemetryInitializer`) it displays all executions correctly.

[image: App insights query]

EDIT:
This is my startup code

```
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CloudRoleNameInitializer>();

        // more registrations
    }
```

and CloudRoleNameInitializer

```
 public class CloudRoleNameInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
 {
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "EmailPuller";
    }
 }
```

When I click run query in application Insights the query generated is

```
requests
| project timestamp, id, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'emailpuller-UNIQUE_ID_FROM_ARM_TEMPLATE' and operation_Name =~ 'OurOperationName'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 20
```

So you can see `cloud_RoleName` is different than set by `ITelemetryInitializer`. If I update query to use 'emailpuller' it returns information on executions

Comment: I tried but didn't reproduce your problem. can you offer more information?  The code of your function app, function.json, host.json, etc...

Comment: Maybe its because you didnt change CloudRoleName? Maybe this monitor uses same query as its shows when I click Run query on AppInsights - IT doesnt return anything unless I fix CloudRoleName in it.

Comment: @PiotrPerak, could you please let us know how do you register the TelemetryInitializer? as far as I know, there is a related bug which cannot register it. If we know this, it'll be easy to reproduce the issue and find the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right. The Monitor UI uses `the default CloudRoleName` to query the logs.

It's easy to find the root cause. The steps are as below:

1.Nav to azure portal -> your azure function -> Monitor -> press F12 to open the Develop Tool of the browser.

2.then click the `Refresh` button -> then in the Develop tool, select the api -> then in the `Request Payload`, you can see this api uses the default `CloudRoleName` to query the logs.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

This may be a bug, you can raise an issue in [github of Azure function](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues).

Comment: I did create a bug altough I doubt this service will have access to my custom cloud role name - https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1755